# Dynamic number of columns in CSS / Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want a web page with one column on phones (portrait), two columns on phone (landscape), and three columns on everything larger.  How do I set that up?  I'm using Bootstrap 3 but I've been unable to achieve the desired results.

I was thinking that I should define a breakpoint for each case.  Pseudocode

```
@media phone portrait {
    .mywidth { max-width: 100%; }
}

@media phone landscape {
    .mywidth  { max-width: 50%; }
}

@media anything bigger {
    .mywidth { max-width: 33.33%; }
}
```

Then have `<div class="mywidth">` in the document.  Is that right?  Can anyone help me out with syntax / breakpoints?  Thanks

Comment: By overwriting hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md and col-xs col-sm col-md bootstrap classes it didn't work?

Comment: I don't know how to do that to achieve my desired result.